# How can I make a conditional Loopin Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple number guess game in java. The program is supposed to be generate a random number between 0 and 10 and I want users to guess it. If the guessed number is lower, the programs displays a message indicates that the guessed number is lower and wants users to guess it until the right number. I made this program as below. However, it finishes right away. How could I modify my code for making users to guess it until the right number guessed? I think it's something about conditional loop but I couldn't figure it out.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int realNumber = rnd.nextInt(11);

        System.out.println("generated number is "+ realNumber + " (for test purposes)"); //Displaying generated number for test purposes

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your guess number between 0 and 10 ====>");
        int guessedNumber = input.nextInt();

        if(guessedNumber > realNumber){
            System.out.println("My number is lower than " + guessedNumber + " guess lower!");
        }else if(guessedNumber < realNumber){
            System.out.println("My number is higher than " + guessedNumber + " guess higher!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Yes! That's my number!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(<condition>) { ... }`

Comment: First hit on google for `java conditional loop`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: All looping is conditional.

Comment: @Karatay I would recommend reading the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in the [help]. This site is not a site to get people to do work for you, it's for helping people who have legitimate difficulties with a problem. In particular, this question is showing no research effort (a simple Google search based on your question title shows literally hundreds if not thousands of tutorials). If you've actually gone through one or more of these and *then* have further issues, people will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean flag = true;   // initialize flag with true value;

do{   
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your guess number between 0 and 10 ====>");
    int guessedNumber = input.nextInt();

    if(guessedNumber > realNumber){
        System.out.println("My number is lower than " + guessedNumber + " guess lower!");

    }else if(guessedNumber < realNumber){
        System.out.println("My number is higher than " + guessedNumber + " guess higher!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Yes! That's my number!");
        flag = false;   // when condition satisfies change the flag to false to break the loop.
    }
}while(flag)
```

you have to use looping, first initialize your flag with true, then when your condition satisfies make it false to break your loop;

Comment: I won't recommend teaching `do-while` with a `true` statement for beginners.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It will execute until condition satisfies that why I use `true` in while loop. Please assist me if any issue.

Comment: I think you don't get my point. It is better to show that a loop must finish when a condition is met in the proper place instead of using an infinite loop and the `break` statement, at least for beginners.

Comment: Well that's what I am looking for. As @LuiggiMendoza wrote, I am beginner in java however I can learn do while loop. Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 2):

An example:

```
boolean wrongAnswer = true;
while(wrongAnswer){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your guess number between 0 and 10 ====>");
    int guessedNumber = input.nextInt();

    if(guessedNumber > realNumber){
        System.out.println("My number is lower than " + guessedNumber + " guess lower!");

    }else if(guessedNumber < realNumber){
        System.out.println("My number is higher than " + guessedNumber + " guess higher!");
    }else{
        wrongAnswer = false;
        System.out.println("Yes! That's my number!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an infinite loop. You need to set `wrongAnswer = false`, not `true` when the correct answer is entered.